# laravel4.2 pass parameter to email blade

Tags: mysql, email, cron, parameter-passing, laravel-4.2

I created cronjobcommand.php at \app\commands\

```
public function fire()  {
  $dataArray=tb1::select();
  $dataArray->get();
  foreach($dataArray as $show){
    Mail::send('emails.test', $show, function($message){
        $message->to($show['user_address'], $show['email_content']);
        $message->subject($show['email_subject']);
    });
  }
}
```

my view, test.blade.php, are as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
<body>
  <h2>This is testing email. {{{  $dataArray->email_content }}}</h2>
  <div>This is testing email.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It works when i remove all the variables and hard code the email address, contents and subject.  however, it fail when i pass some variables into the section of Mail::send.....

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$users = DB::table('table')->get();
foreach($dataArray as $show){
Mail::send('emails.test', array('FIELD1'=>$user->FIELD1, 
                                'FIELD2'=>$user->FIELD2),
           function($message) use ($show) {
 $message->to($show->user_address, $show->email_content)
         ->subject($show->email_subject);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `$show` variable is not available inside the callback, its only available in your mail html template.

Try this;

```
public function fire()  {
    // Assuming this is the database query
    $dataArray=tb1::select()->get();

    foreach($dataArray as $show){
        $mailData = $show->toArray();

        Mail::send('emails.test', $mailData, function($message) use($show){
            $message->to($show->user_address, $show->email_content);
            $message->subject($show->email_subject);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It failed.  I try to leave the email content as an variables and passing to the view, hard code the address and the subject: $message->to('me@company.com', $show['email_content'])->subject('tesitng');

Comment: Can you paste the error message. Also remember that the `$message->to()` should receive a string representation of either the recipient's name or email address. Also on your mail view template, you're trying to access an array element as an object property which would also throw an error. Can you try `$message->to($show['user_address'], 'Username');` Also on your template view change `{{{ $dataArray->email_content }}}` to `{{$email_content}}`. Then let me know how it goes. Paste the error message in case you get an error.

Comment: I try:


foreach($dataArray as $show){

  Mail::send('emails.test', $show, function($message) use ($show) {
  $message->to('me@company.com', 'myName')->subject('testing');
});
}

view:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
  <body><h2>This is testing email. {{{ $email_content }}}</h2></body>
</html>


the log is clear (app\storage\logs), there is no error, no message receive

Answer (score 0):

Can you try logging the `$show`variable just to be sure that it actually has some data then paste the logs. Try this;

```
foreach($dataArray as $show) {
    dd($show);

    ... //omitted the rest of the code for brevity
}
```

Comment: it has value shown on the  command prompt. however, no log found in \app\storage\logs

Comment: What is the type of the value, e.g an object, an array or string?

Comment: [ErrorException]Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::send() must be of the type array, object given, called in ...\Facades\Facade.php on line 214 and defined

Comment: Sorry had forgotten that the send method accepts an array as the second argument. Check the edit.